# svsnversion.exe throws Error on rebuild solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tortoisesvn

When I made the last Rebuild of a VB.NET solution in Visual Studio 2010 I got an error:

> svnversion.exe exited with Code1

Where does this error come from? And what I am going to do to remove that error?

Comment: Show the **full string** of calling `svnversion.exe`. We can't read it frim your brain

Comment: Thank you lazy Badger for comment, Unfortunately I am out of office this week, I will post the whole error message next monday.

Comment: Hello Lazy Badger,  teh Code message is in German: Fehler 6 "svnversion.exe" wurde mit Code 1 beendet. D:\Bibliothek\Eigene Dokumente\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BatchTools\EMEBatchTools5\AdjustmentGUI\AdjustmentGUI.vbproj 332 5 AdjustmentGUI   , in English Error 6 synversion.exe was ended with code 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. At first it grew up, commit and revert was impossible, great problem in the whole solution. In a final step we copied the solution files from another machine to my system and it works.